# How does Flutter rebuild a subtree that has changed?

Tags: flutter

I know it calls updateChild (or updatechildren) for each child from the root of the subtree that has changed, but how does this algorithm works? Say you have a Column with two children (w1, w2) and each of these again has a child (w1-1, w2-1). In what order does it update this w1-1 and w2-1? Where can I find the algorithm for this?

Comment: Refer to official documentation : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Element/rebuild.html

Answer (score 0):

In your IDE, you can select any build() method, select "go to definition" via the right click menu, then from there select "go to references".  A few of those will obviously be the code that calls the build(), which is what you're curious about.  Have fun exploring the well-commented Flutter SDK!

Edit: that won't quite work, because the definition is right there.  Instead, find "go to symbol" in your IDE, and go to "build", then "references".

Comment: That is what I've done but this part of the puzzle remains unsolved.. don't understand all of the source code, that's why I'm asking here.